# MySQL stored function SELECT INTO unexpected results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a stored function in mysql 5.1 that returns the value 'AccountIDref' for a given room. If I only query the inner SELECT statement this works (returns the value for room). But invoking the function I get the response:

'#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row'

```
CREATE FUNCTION getAccountId (room INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE refID INT DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT AccountIDref INTO refID FROM Allocation
    WHERE Room = room;
    RETURN refID;
END
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: ah forgot: example is simplified but there should not be more than one row in this case. I have the impression, the WHERE clause is just ignored somehow...

Answer (score 1):

Field name and parameter name must be different -

```
CREATE FUNCTION getAccountId (room_param INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE refID INT DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT AccountIDref INTO refID FROM Allocation
    WHERE Room = room_param;
    RETURN refID;
END
```

In your function you were getting all tables records.

Answer (score 0):

What I am going to suggest isn't going to be much different from what you have, but I am skeptical about the `where` clause being in the next line and also let's use `limit 1` to explicitly set the limit.

Try this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION getAccountId (room INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE refID INT DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT AccountIDref INTO refID FROM Allocation WHERE Room = room LIMIT 1;
    RETURN refID;
END
```

Comment: Meeeh did not help. Now I get the ID of the first table entry as result.